# Pass and Updating Value Realtime between two form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, winsock

I created an app that can communicate each other through winsock. the app can send text to other pc then received via a method in form 1 and saved as variable. i am trying to make the received data can be displayed realtime in form 2 via a rich text box. but so far i can only pass the value when form 2 load, but i cannot make the value updated and added realtime, so it works like a log system. how i can make those two form work at the same time, one is for sending data and receiving it, while the other for displaying the data received.

code on form 1

```
 Public Sub ReceiveSock_DataArrival(sender As Object, e As Winsock2005DLL.WinsockDataArrivalEventArgs) Handles ReceiveSock.DataArrival
    Try
        ReceiveSock.Get(IncomingMessage)
        IncomingMessage = IncomingMessage + vbNewLine
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + IncomingMessage
        Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = Form2.RichTextBox1.Text + IncomingMessage + vbNewLine
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

On Form 2

`Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = ""
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = Me.RichTextBox1.Text + Form1.IncomingMessage
    End Sub`

[my app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GDpT.png)

Comment: How do you instantiate Form2? Sounds like you are using the default instance instead of the one you created.

Comment: i instantiate form2 using the button on form 1. i don't really understand what you mean on instance, pardon me

Comment: what is your code in that button that creates Form2

Comment: `Public Sub PictureBox27_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox27.Click

        Dim pesanForm As New Form2()
        pesanForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub`

Comment: use `pesanForm` instead of `Form2` in your `ReciveSock_DataArrival` event handler also make sure it is declared at the Class level instead of the method level.

Comment: Did that help, or do I need to expound further ?